# Node.js - Certain headers are not being set

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

As i stated in the title, I tried setting headers in node.js, but some of them just would not stick/would get overwritten.

Here is content of my server.js file:

```
const next = require("next");
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
http
 .createServer((req, res) => {
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
  res.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
  res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  res.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
  res.setHeader(
    "Strict-Transport-Security",
    "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  );
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31557600");
  handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
})
.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on PORT ${port}`);
  });
});
```

Every header except Cache-control and x-powered-by (its not in code but i tried) is getting set.
Weird thing is that when i log response, my headers are loged out:

```
'x-content-type-options': [ 'X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff' ],
'x-frame-options': [ 'X-Frame-Options', 'DENY' ],
'x-xss-protection': [ 'X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block' ],
'strict-transport-security': [
  'Strict-Transport-Security',
  'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'
],
'cache-control': [ 'Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600' ]
```

There are the headers that i have in my browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
X-Powered-By: Next.js
ETag: "1373f-5S13UfVtDhxl5s8GCDKvO1iq/oY"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Thu, 06 Feb 2020 17:13:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Any idea whats happening here? Some default setting overwriting my custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is specific to Next.js framework.

Regarding 'X-Powered-By', this is expected, as per the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/disabling-x-powered-by)

> By default Next.js will add x-powered-by to the request headers. To opt-out of it, open next.config.js and disable the poweredByHeader config:

Regarding 'Cache-Control', it looks like it is overwritten by Next.js in development mode as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/db90ffe1ea7fe4c3dde86fce8e45470c803a7063/packages/next/server/next-dev-server.ts#L488)

```
sendHTML(req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse, html: string) {
    // In dev, we should not cache pages for any reason.
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, must-revalidate')
    return super.sendHTML(req, res, html)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i feel dumb for not inspecting a bit more. Just one question, do you think its safe/good practice to change cache headers in source code?